# Cobertura - JSR/RET are not supported

Tags: java, ant, junit, cobertura

I am getting this error "JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames option" for some of my classes when running Cobertura - how do I fix this?

Comment: What version of cobertura are you using? Also I would need to see code in order to reproduce the bug and provide a fix. You could raise this issue on the github issues page: https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura

Comment: Does someone have a solution for this already?